# Fast algorithm to find thousands of points in millions polygon?

Tags: java, algorithm, point

I tried to find out thousands  of point in million polygon via web services .At first i implemented the  algorithm(Point in polygon) in java ,but it take a long time .And then i split the table in mysql and tried to using the multiple thread to solve it ,but still inefficiently.  Is there any faster algorithm or implementation for solve this?

Plus description about the polygon. 2D ,static,complex polygon(also with hole).

Any Suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: How about writing your algorithm in CUDA and running it on a GPU ;)?

Answer (score 3):

Testing a point against a million polygons is going to take a lot of time, no matter how efficient your point in polygon function is.

You need to narrow down the search list. Start by making a bounding box for each polygon and only selecting the polygons when the point is within the bounding box.

If the polygons are unchanging you could convert each polygon to a set of triangles. Testing to see if a point is in a triangle should be much faster than testing to see if it's in an arbitrary polygon. Even though the number of triangles will be much larger than the number of polygons, it might be faster overall.

Comment: If hit test function is O(1) or O(|size of polygon|) then millions of polygon is no matter. Also triangulation of complex polygons is not easy task.

Answer (score 3):

If the collection of polygons is static it may be helpful to first register them onto a spatial data structure - an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) might be a good choice, assuming that the polygons do not overlap each other too much.

To test a point against the polygon collection the enclosing leaf in the tree would first be found (an `O(log(n))` style operation) and then it would only be necessary to perform the full point-in-polygon test for the polygons that are associated with the enclosing leaf.

This approach should greatly speed up each point test, but requires an additional setup phase to build the R-tree.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with millions of polygons, you need some kind of space partitioning, or it's gonna be slow, no matter how optimized your hit-test function is or how many threads work on solving your query.

What kind of space partitioning ? *it depends*:

- 2D? 3D?
- Is your polygon set static? If not, do it changes frequently?
- What kind of request are you doing on this set?
- What kind of polygon is it? Triangle? Convex? Concave? Complex? With holes?

We need more information to help you.

**EDIT**

Here is a simple space partitioning scheme.

Suppose there is a Cartesian grid over your 2D space with a given step.

When you add a polygon:

- Compute its bounding box
- Find all the grid cells that intersect with the bounding box
- For each cell, add a line in a special table.

The table looks like this: `cell_x`, `cell_y`, `polygon_id`. Add the proper indexes (at least `cell_x` and `cell_y`)

Of course, you want to choose your grid step so most of the polygons lay in less than 10 cells, or else your cell table will quickly becomes huge.

It's now easy to find the polygons at a given point:

- Compute in which cell your point belongs
- Get all polygons associated to this cell
- For each polygon, use your hit-test function

This solution is far from optimal, but easy to implements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I will edit the question to add up these information.

Answer (score 0):

I thik here is the case where divide and conquer would do, you could try making subpolyons or simplifying some of the poonts, maybe try an heuristic approach, there are my 5 cents.